# Java cannot find enum variable

Tags: java, enums

I am having issues calling the `Severity.LOW` variable from the `Enum` I created. I have tried importing it, wrapping it in a class, and importing the wrapper class. I cannot figure out what im doing wrong.

Here is the `Main.java`

```
package allergyProblem;

import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter First Name:");

        String firstName = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter Last Name:");

        String lastName = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter Phone Number:");

        String phoneNumber = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter E-Mail Address:");

        String emailAddress = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter Street Name:");

        String streetName = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter City:");

        String city = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter State:");

        String state = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter Zipcode:");

        int zipCode = sc.nextInt();

        Address adr = new Address(streetName, city, state, zipCode);

        Allergy allergy = new Allergy("coughing", "Arzoo", Severity.LOW, "Regular cough");

        List<Allergy> allergies = new ArrayList<Allergy>();
        allergies.add(allergy);

        Patient patient = new Patient(firstName, lastName, phoneNumber, emailAddress, adr, allergies);

        System.out.println(patient);

    }
}
```

Here is the `Enum` im trying to access

```
package allergyProblem;

import java.util.*;

public enum Severity {HIGH, MEDIUM, LOW}
```

This is the error i get when trying to compile `Main.java`.
`Severity.java` which is the `Enum`, compiled properly without any errors.

```
Main.java:43: error: cannot find symbol
                Allergy allergy = new Allergy("coughing", "Arzoo", Severity.LOW, "Regular cough");
                                                                           ^
  symbol:   variable LOW
  location: class Severity
1 error
```

Comment: Did you compile `Severity.java`? Are you using an IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is telling you that `Severity` as a type is found (ignore that it says 'class Severity', it does that even if javac knows it is an enum, unfortunately), but that it does not contain the variable `LOW`.

There's only one explanation for that:

The `Severity` that javac is using here is *NOT* the result of compiling `public enum Severity {HIGH, MEDIUM, LOW}`. Check if there are other classes named Severity in your classpath in that package, or in the package that contains your `Main.java` file. Then, check that you properly (re)compiled Severity.java, because a stale class file can also mess with it. Then check that you don't have some old stale build result on the class path.

NB: Note that your code won't work even after fixing this, you're abusing Scanner. The right way to use scanner is to either only call .nextLine, or to never call it, with a strong preference for never calling it. If you want to read lines, after making the scanner, immediately run `scanner.useDelimiter("\r?\n");` in order to tell the scanner that you want one token per enter, not one token per whitespace (this is a good idea in any case when taking command line input, the fact that scanner defaults to whitespace as delimiter is a dumb error that cannot be fixed due to backwards compatibility concerns. It's a good habit to get into: Making a scanner? Immediately set the delimiter). Then, you can just call `next()` instead of `nextLine()` for a lines worth of data, and then it will work - your take will not work due to well known issues mixing nextLine and nextAnythingElse.

Comment: I did have another class named Severity in the package. That did it, Thank you! I will also fix the Scanner properly.